# Does cake have support for windows impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, cakebuild

I need to use cake to install an application, and I need it to run as the user that later will run the application. Is this possible with cake in windows, by impersonation this user?

Comment: When the application is installed, won't that be done by the same user when the app is run later?  If so I wouldn't have expected anything to be done as that's typical for installed Windows apps?   Unless of course you are installing some sort of Windows Service and/or equivalent that runs in a different account

Comment: The application is installed by a user but it is a windows service and it is installed so that it runs under a different user. (Windows services run under whatever user they are set up to run under)

Comment: @Greg Schmidt - https://cakebuild.net/

Comment: Ah, Cake build, not CakePHP. I see that the tags have now been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

[Cake](https://cakebuild.net/) is actually using "normal" c# code, so there is probably nothing stopping you from using ["normal" impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-6.0).

It would probably be much easier, though, to simply run the Cake script as another user. You can do this, for example, by using the [RunAs command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525%28v=ws.11%29) or utilizing [PsExec from the sysinternals tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).